# Computing wrong value of integral using simpsons rule

Tags: python, integration, simpsons-rule

I wrote the following piece of code for Simpson's rule integration to approximate sin. The equation is in this [attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xsh7.png). I wrote separate loops for the even and odd terms, as they are shown grouped in the attachment.

```
import math 

x1=0
x2=math.pi
N=6
delta_x=(x2-x1)/N
f=math.sin
sum=f(0)

#odd summation
for i in range (1,N+1):
    sum=sum+f(x1+(2*i+1)*delta_x)

sum=4*sum
print(sum)

#even summation

for i in range(2,N+1):
    sumeven=0
    sumeven=sumeven+f(x1+(2*i)*delta_x)
sumeven=2*sumeven

sumeven=sumeven+f(N)
print(sumeven)

integral=(delta_x/3)*(sum+sumeven) 
print(integral)
```

But when I print the values, it gives me very small negative numbers.

Can anyone see what is wrong with my code?

Comment: I haven't really dug into it, but the first thing I'd check is whether you're getting integer division somewhere. At least if you're on Python 2.

Comment: Just glancing at your code, you use `sumeven=0` *inside* your loop, i.e. reseting the `sumeven` value to `0` on each iteration, making you get only the last value, not the sum of the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, learn some basic debugging.  You've done only two simple `print` lines for this code, neither of which traces the more detailed problems.  See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.  I added some instrumentation, cleaned up some style, and ran the code again, tracing the logic and data flow somewhat better.  Diagnosis below.

```
sum_odd = f(0)

# odd summation
for i in range (1, N+1):
    x_val = x1 + (2*i+1)*delta_x
    sum_odd = sum_odd + f(x_val)
    print (x_val/math.pi, "pi", f(x_val), sum_odd)

sum_odd = 4*sum_odd

print(sum_odd)

# even summation
for i in range(2, N+1):
    sum_even = 0
    x_val = x1 + (2*i)*delta_x
    sum_even = sum_even + f(x_val)
    print (x_val/math.pi, "pi", f(x_val), sum_even)
```

Output:

```
0.5 pi 1.0 1.0
0.8333333333333333 pi 0.5000000000000003 1.5000000000000004
1.1666666666666665 pi -0.4999999999999997 1.0000000000000007
1.5 pi -1.0 6.661338147750939e-16
1.8333333333333333 pi -0.5000000000000004 -0.4999999999999998
2.1666666666666665 pi 0.4999999999999993 -4.996003610813204e-16
-1.9984014443252818e-15
0.6666666666666666 pi 0.8660254037844387 0.8660254037844387
1.0 pi 1.2246467991473532e-16 1.2246467991473532e-16
1.3333333333333333 pi -0.8660254037844384 -0.8660254037844384
1.6666666666666665 pi -0.866025403784439 -0.866025403784439
2.0 pi -2.4492935982947064e-16 -2.4492935982947064e-16
-0.27941549819892636
-0.04876720424671586
```

**DIAGNOSIS**

You have two immediate problems:

1. You initialize sum_even *inside* the loop, which discards prior computations for that half of the series.  Move it before the loop.
2. You integrated over *twice* the specified range; this, alone, will get you a tiny value (ideally, this would be 0, the integral for a full cycle of the function).

Fix the initialization, fix the limits, and you should see good results, more like this:

```
0.16666666666666666 pi 0.49999999999999994 0.49999999999999994
0.5 pi 1.0 1.5
0.8333333333333333 pi 0.5000000000000003 2.0000000000000004
8.000000000000002
0.3333333333333333 pi 0.8660254037844386 0.8660254037844386
0.6666666666666666 pi 0.8660254037844387 1.7320508075688772
1.0 pi 1.2246467991473532e-16 1.7320508075688774
3.184686116938829
1.9520959854268212
```

Also, I strongly recommend that you work through tutorials on debugging and coding style; these will help you in future work.  I know from experience.  :-)

Comment: I'm sorry, I fail to see how I integrated over twice the specified range.

Comment: @Soffie: That's one reason I put in the extra `print` statements, to show the actual values you're using.  Look at how you calculate the `x` value in each loop: your `2*i` term drives it to twice the specified upper limit.

Comment: ah ok- but I need 2*i+1 and the 2*i for odd and even respectively so I can sum up the delta_x's multiplied by(1,3,5)...and (2,4,6..) for the odd and even terms. Do I need to go about it a different way?

Comment: Yes.  Check your algebra, and compare to the `x` values you actually need.